# Как вывести натуральные числа подряд и определить цифру на определенной позиции в Python?

Tags: python, математика

У меня есть задача - нужно выписать натуральные числа от 1 до бесконечности подряд и определить, какая цифра будет на позиции 206787.

> P.S Мне заблокировали вопросы и попросили их улучшить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ну если не важно время и память, то можно сделать так:**

```
text = ''
value = 1
while len(text) < 206787:
    text += str(value)
    value += 1

print(text[206787])
```

**если же важны (а в задачах они важны) :), то придется делать так:**

сначала идут 1циферные числа (9 штук), затем 2циферные числа (90 штук), затем 3циферные числа (900 штук), затем... вы заметили зависимость?

таким образом у вас получается задача состоящая из трех подзадач:

1. определение каким xциферным числом будет число на 206787 позиции

для этого надо в том же вольфрам альфа посмотреть формулу для суммы ряда

```
9 + 90 + 900 + ... = 9 * (10^0 + 10^1 + 10^2 + ... + 10^n)
```

вам как раз надо найти этот самый n и понять сколько цифр будет в числа

2. дальше зная на каком знаке начинаются xциферные числа вычисляем какое по порядку xциферное число находится на 206787 позиции (вернее его цифра на этой позиции)

   ```
   (206787 - позиция xциферного числа) / x
   ```
3. ну и дальше зная число легко получить и цифру на его позиции

   ```
   (206787 - позиция xциферного числа) % x
   ```

Comment: все же я смог решить задачу в одну строчку 'print(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,1000000)])[206786])'

Comment: халявщик :) я решал подобную задачу, правда там позиция цифры была в районе 10^100 со всеми вытекающими :)

Answer (score 0):

Я взял и немного сделал улучшил твой код ''сprint(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,1000000)])[206786])'''

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]